# PHP String Split/Explode

Tags: php, string, split, explode

I have a String **"Hello I am apple"**
I want to split to **two** string

> str1 = "Hello"
>
> str2 = "I am apple"

so just simply split by the **first space**, then the following words will be in one string

Comment: substr at the strpos of the first space

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a question that could be answered by looking at readily available PHP resources such as the documentation

Answer (score 4):

Explode function has a 3rd parameter for that:

> **limit**
>
> If limit is set and positive, the returned array will contain a maximum of limit elements with the last element containing the rest of string.

http://php.net/explode

```
list($str1, $str2) = explode(" ", $str, 2);
```

Comment: Excellent answer! Compact and precise.

Answer (score 0):

Same result also can be achieved by following code....

```
<?php
$str = "Hello I am Apple";
$str_con = explode(" ",$str,2);
echo $str_con[0];
echo $str_con[1];
?>
```